# Convergence of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\frac{\left(\log\left(1+i/n\right)\right)^2}{1+i/n}\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Sequence of real numbers
$$S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left[\frac{\left(\log\left(1+\frac{i}{n}\right)\right)^2}{1+\frac{i}{n}}\right]$$

Does $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} S_n$ exist? If so, compute the value.

**My Solution:**

A)
According to Cauchy's first theorem on limits.

This limit will be same as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\frac{(\log(1+\frac{n}{n}))^2}{1+\frac{n}{n}}\right] =\frac{(\log(2))^2}{2}$$

B) $S_n$ can also be written as $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(\log(1+x))^2}{1+x}dx=\frac{(\log(2))^3}{3}$$

Two answers by two methods. What am I missing here? Is this sequence not convergent?

Comment: The argument in $A$ is wrong. Cauchy's first theorem apply to a single sequence $$a_k \to a \implies \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \to a$$ In your case, your "$a_k$" also depend on $n$. i.e You have a double sequence depends on two indices $n$ and $i$. Even when the limit exists along the diagonal, it doesn't tell you anything about the limit of sums along another direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy's first theorem doesn't apply.  The sequence of values you are summing together changes with $n$.

Comment: Sir could you please , elaborate your answer a little bit, i did not get that.

Comment: @NewBornMATH See achille hui's comment on the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by B) is correct and the sequence seems to be convergent. Now, does Cuuchy's theorem apply here ? I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

the B) methods is true. 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{(\ln{1+\dfrac{i}{n}})^2}{1+\dfrac{i}{n}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$$

where $$f(x)=\dfrac{\left(\ln{(1+x)}\right)^2}{1+x}$$